# Enzyme wrapper doesn't change when state/props are changed

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

EDIT (MyTable.js component has):

```
render () {

  // I manipulate this.props here and assign some of them to bootstrapTableProps

  return (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <BootstrapTable {bootstrapTableProps}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

(in MyTable.spec.js test case I have):

```
let wrapper = shallow(
  <MyTable
    {...someProps}
  />
);

// change state
wrapper.setState({sortName: 'timestamp', sortOrder: 'asc'});

let bootstrapTableWrapper = wrapper.find('BootstrapTable');
let timestamps = bootstrapTableWrapper.prop('data').map(row => row.timestamp);
expect(timestamps).to.be.ascending; // CORRECT, sorted to be ascending

// change state second time
wrapper.setState({sortName: 'timestamp', sortOrder: 'desc'});

let timestamps = bootstrapTableWrapper.prop('data').map(row => row.timestamp);
expect(timestamps).to.be.descending; // ERROR, still ascending

// recreate the inner wrapper
bootstrapTableWrapper = wrapper.find('BootstrapTable');
let timestamps = bootstrapTableWrapper.prop('data').map(row => row.timestamp);
expect(timestamps).to.be.descending; // CORRECT, descending
```

---

So, in the test I change state (and/or props) on the outer `wrapper` with  `wrapper.setState(...)` or `wrapper.setProps({...});`. Then I assert that the correct properties are passed to the inner component.

Next, I again make `wrapper.setState(...)` or `wrapper.setProps({...});`. Then I assert that the updated properties were passed to the before created `bootstrapTableWrapper`. **But nothing happens.**

Prior to checking that the new properties were passed to the `bootstrapTableWrapper` I have to recreate it `bootstrapTableWrapper = wrapper.find('BootstrapTable');` and only **then I see the change**.

Is the reason for this that `wrapper.find` makes a deep copy of the found component(s), so that the change on the original component does not affect it?

Answer (score 0):

Shallow only operate on `one level`, it will not create a deep level component, and thus you won't be able to see changes in any case in the inner component.

Besides, rather than testing some values of `BootstrapTable` in `MyTable` test's file, define the test in `BootstrapTable` test's file... `jest`

One hack than you can do is this:

`let bootstrapTableWrapper = wrapper.find(BootstrapTable).shallow();`
and  thus `bootstrapTableWrapper` is a shallow of your component.

But I really recommand  to move all tests concerning `BootstrapTable` to its own test file.

Comment: Thanks. Well, what I have is MyTable.js, and inside a div and inside that div two components BootstrapTable and TableTitle for example defined in another files. I do a shallow of MyTable and i examine the props passed to BootstrapTable. This should be possible to examine with the shallow wrapper of MyTable?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear what I do. I think with shallow I should be able to assert the properties passed to BootstrapTable (as this is part of MyTable component test), but not the inner content of the BootstrapTable?

Comment: Try seeing the other comment. and operating on the instance directly

Comment: I tryed that solution, doesn't pass not even 1st expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the state or props on the same instance of wrapper and assert on the same instance

```
wrapper.instance().setState({
        sortOrder:'desc' 
       })
```

so even for the assertion it needs to be on the same instance of wrapper.

Comment: I tryed this solution, doesn't pass not even 1st expect. Don't understand why would I operate on the instance, instead on the wrapper.